# Why am I getting the average equals to zero

Tags: java

i do not know why i am getting the average = 0. the code below shows how i calculate it, and the image posted below shows what i am getting as output

**Code**

```
    float avg = (goodMatchesList.size()/rawMatchesListSorted.size()) * 100;
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "avg: " + avg);
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "min: " + minDist);
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "max: " + maxDist);
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "objComputedDescExt.rows: " + matFactory.getComputedDescExtMatAt(0).rows());
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "rawMatchesListSorted.size: " + rawMatchesListSorted.size());
    Log.D(TAG, "descMatcher", "goodMatchesList.size: " + goodMatchesList.size());
```

[image]

Comment: Integer division? *checks code* Yup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dividing two integers - `(goodMatchesList.size()/rawMatchesListSorted.size())`, so if the result is smaller than 1, it becomes 0.

For floating point division, use casting :

```
((float)goodMatchesList.size()/rawMatchesListSorted.size())*100
```

or multiple by 100 before dividing if you don't care about fractions:

```
100*goodMatchesList.size()/rawMatchesListSorted.size()
```